# Разница в доступе

Tags: java

Есть ли разница в плане доступа к полям `a` и `b`?

```
// X.java
package XY;
class X
{
  int a;
};

// Y.java 
package XY;
class Y
{
  public int b;
};
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html CTRL+F package-private

Comment: @Etki только от туда, этого момента не понял

Comment: они же прямо приводят таблицу доступа с примерами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модификатор доступа `public` у класса/метода/поля и т.д - обратиться можно отовсюду. Если его не указать, то к нему можно будет обратиться только из класса, где она объявлена и из всего `package`.

Если класс без модификатора, то модификаторы его составляющих (методы, поля и т.д) уходят на второй план. На первом стоит сам класс. То есть, если поле `public` будет в классе без модификатора, то к ней нельзя будет обратиться из сабкласса или из другого `package`

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: Если вы не напишите модификатор, то переменная будет доступна в классе где она объявлена и во всем `package`.

Comment: Так и со всеми методами, константами и т.д

Comment: Хух, вы меня запутали)

Comment: В моём случае класс X имеет модификатор доступа default, а его поле a - public?

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Спасибо, именно это я и имел в виду

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько уровней доступа:

1. `default` - применяется когда не указан модификатор доступа. В этом случае переменная доступна самому классу где она указана, его внутренним классам и всем классам в одном пакете с этим.
2. `private` - доступно только самому классу и его внутренним классам
3. `protected` - доступно самому классу, его внутренним классам и его наследникам
4. `public` - доступно всем и везде

Comment: Меня интересует 4 пункт, если класс указан без модификатора, то он default, верно? А если у него есть поле public, то оно ведь не сможет быть доступно везде, ведь сам класс default?

Comment: Ответ мой прочитайте внимательно

Comment: Извините, насчёт `default` -  внутренним классам обратиться нельзя

Comment: @СергейГрушин, только что проверил - внутренние классы имеют абсолютно полный доступ к внешнему классу. Даже к приватным полям

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html тут есть таблица и в ней написано что если класс default, то внутренние к ним доступа не имеют.

Comment: @monkey, да, по идее, если класс - дефолтный, то к его полям не будет доступа из других пакетов.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, кажется вы путаете внутренние классы с sub-классами, т.е. расширяющими к-л класс. http://ideone.com/FBskwb